# Spring MVC Form validation error message 

Tags: java, forms, jsp, spring-mvc

I have the following form:

```
<form:form method="POST" action="signin.dlp" commandName="user" >
<form:input path="useremail" id="useremail" /><FONT color="red"><form:errors path="useremail" /></FONT><Br />
<form:password path="pswd" id="pswd" /><FONT color="red"><form:errors path="pswd" /></FONT> <br />
<input id ="login" type="submit" value="Login"></input>                                 
</form:form>
```

and then I i have Validator which validates value from and send error.

what I would like to do is to add extra error label, for example

```
<form:errors path="generarError" />
```

and inside my validator I can do the following:

```
if (user.getA().equals(user.getB()))
 errors.rejectValue("generarError",
                "lengthOfUser.user.generarError",
                "A is not equeal to B. Sorry");
          }
```

The important thing that I generalError is not member of user object.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you cannot bind an error to the nonexistent field.

However, if you want to show an error that belongs to the form as a whole rather then to one of its fields, you can do the following:

```
<form:errors />
```

.

```
errors.reject("lengthOfUser.user.generarError",  "A is not equeal to B. Sorry");
```